# How do i convert this SQL Query into Neo4j Cypher Query?

Tags: sql, neo4j, cypher, syntax-error, concatenation

> The SQL Query is as follows :

```
SELECT * FROM database.tablename WHERE concat(id, code) IN ('1234PQR', '4567ABC')
```

---

> The Neo4j Cypher Query which i wanted to Convert is as follows :

```
MATCH (n:tablename)
WITH n.id+n.code AS p
WHERE p IN ["1234PQR","4567ABC"]
RETURN n
```

This Returns me an error

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError
Variable `n` not defined (line 4, column 10 (offset: 160))
```

***So where am i doing it wrong?*** As per the SQL Query I'm concatenating two columns to get desired values to compare.

---

Kindly Correct my Cypher Query and if it's totally wrong give me the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Found the Answer to my Above query :

```
MATCH (n:tablename) WHERE(n.id+n.code) IN ["1234PQR","4567ABC"] RETURN n
```

Comment: Looks good, but keep in mind the parenthesis in your WHERE clause aren't necessary in this case.